# Dispose a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to dispose my JFrame with the following method:

```java
private void killJFrame(JFrame jFrame) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> jFrame.dispose());
}
```

When `killJFrame()` is executed, the `JFrame` becomes invisible and it seems like it worked.
However, when calling `Frame.getFrames()`, the returned array still contains all of the `JFrame`s which were created in my application.

There is no difference if I try it like this:

```java
private void killJFrame(JFrame jFrame) {
     jFrame.dispose();
}
```

I just thought it would be better if I disposed my `JFrame` on the event dispatch thread.

Why does the returned array of `Frame.getFrames()` still contain my `JFrames`?

Comment: [dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Java uses a garbage collector. Disposing the frame only makes it ready for garbage collection, thus those JFrames exist until the GC comes in and deletes them.</strike>

`JFrame.dispose()` only frees up the *resources*.

In Java, objects are references pointing to a group of resources. So if the memory is cleared, the reference is still left over.